# Pack ServletContainerInitializers from different bundles to a single OSGi bundle

Tags: maven, tomcat, osgi, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm creating an OSGi bundle which consist of following dependencies

```
<artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
<artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
<artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
```

I want to pack the SCIs in both websocket and jasper.

My IncludeResource section is as follows

```
<Include-Resource>
         {maven-resources},
         @tomcat-jasper-${version.tomcat}.jar!/META-INF/*,
         @tomcat-embed-websocket-${version.tomcat}.jar!/META-INF/*,
         src/main/resources
</Include-Resource>
```

Problem here is I'm only getting websocket SCi. I think jasper resources get overridden by the websocket resources. Depend on the order I specify them.

How can I put both resource in the same bundle?

Comment: What is "SCI"? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this. You can use maven-shade-plugin for this.

e.g.
In My scenario I can pack both SCIs as follows

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```